What does "ceo" stand for in Airbus A320ceo?
What does "ceo" stand for in Airbus A320ceo??

It means "Safety tests be damned, the BOSS told me to ship it!"

"In December 2010, Airbus announced the re-engined A320neo (new engine option), which entered service with Lufthansa in January 2016. With more efficient turbofans and improvements including sharklets, it offers up to 15% better fuel economy. The previous A320 generation is now called A320ceo (current engine option)."
Source Wikipedia

what's next A320ueo (updated engine option)?
